# define global variables in a function and pass on to a class

Tags: python, class, function, global-variables

Can any one help please,
I am trying to sample data every x minute from the class PROCESS defined in the code below (which runs whenever called on by other functions not shown here)
to schedule this, I am running a scheduler function every X minute, started by the MAIN function and executed by function minmax_job.

however my function minmax_job doesn't seem to know the initial value of i 
I have tried on and on about putting global variables and so on, but it still doesn't know that i = 0 (initially)

```
i = 0
atc,otc,tssc = 0,0,0
atf,otf,tssf = False,False,False


class Process(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, buffer3, broadcast_server):
        threading.Thread.__init__(self)
        self.setDaemon(True)
        self.buffer3 = buffer3
        self.factory = broadcast_server

    def run(self):
        today = datetime.now()
        global time_of_last_run
        global atv1,atv2,atv3,otv1,otv2,otv3,tssv1,tssv2,tssv3
        global atf,otf,tssf
        global atc,otc,tssc


        if self.buffer3.startswith('kitchen aquarium: temp:'):
            self.temp = self.buffer3.replace('kitchen aquarium: temp:','')
            self.factory.broadcast("Aquarium temperature %s" % self.temp)

            if atc == 1 and atf:
                atv1 = float(self.temp)
                atf = False
            elif atc == 2 and atf:
                atv2 = float(self.temp)
                atf = False 
            elif atc == 3 and atf:
                atv3 = float(self.temp)
                atf = False


def minmax_job():

    global atv1,atv2,atv3,otv1,otv2,otv3,tssv1,tssv2,tssv3
    global atf,otf,tssf
    global atc,otc,tssc,i

    if i == 3:
        i = 0
        atc = 0

    if i < 4:
        atc = atc + 1 
        atf = True
        i = i + 1


if __name__ == '__main__':

    minmax_scheduler = Scheduler()
    minmax_scheduler.add_interval_job(minmax_job, seconds=10)
    minmax_scheduler.start()
```

Comment: Oh dear god! Please take it away!

Comment: @Ossama: Communication between threads through global variables (lots of them in your case) without locks is a recipe for desaster. Also, your `Process` thread has a `run()`-method that executes a few statements and then terminates immediately. Normally, there should be a loop. And your `Process` thread seems to have nothing to do with the problem you describe, since it doesn't operate on `i`.

Comment: @Ossama: Also, if you start numbering your variables, what you really want is a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i needs to be declared as global, then assigned a value at the outer scope as this demo shows

```
global i
i=0

def rabbit():
    global i
    print "rabbit ",i


#main here
if __name__ == '__main__':
    rabbit()
```

Comment: That is not so. It is only necessary that `i` exists in the global namespace or that `i` is assigned a value in `rabbit()` before the `print` statement in `rabbit()` is executed. Declaring `i` global in the global namespace is not needed.

Comment: pillmuncher, I think you are correct but the OP's question has a global i inside a def block.  In the OP's example listing that is what is required to make the scoping work -- according to the OP.  I'll let others critique the code of the OP

Answer (score 0):

**@Pillmuncher**, above, had the right idea as a sub-comment. I'll make it a complete answer.  You're trying to share data between processes and/or threads by means of global variables.  This is a very **INCORRECT** method.  It might work or might not, some of the time, if the phase of the moon is right and you don't change where you put a comment, etc.

The reasons for this are complex, but suffice to say you should find a Comp. Sci. textbook on operating systems and look up the following terms:

- forking
- thread safety
- multiprocessing
- protected memory
- race condition
- message queues
- interprocess communication
- thread locks
- stack memory allocation
- heap memory

In Python, both the multiprocessing and threading modules provides many functions for declaring shared memory and keeping it safe.  You like safe (even if you don't know it yet).  Safe is good.  Safe can be (but isn't always) fast.

If you try to use global variables instead of features from multiprocessing and threading modules, you'll shoot yourself in the foot while hanging yourself from a yardarm:  slowly and painfully and you'll disdain life itself.

So, check out:  http://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html

This has many fine examples of doing things the right way.  Declare your vars ahead of time, pass them into each thread/process, and live the upstanding life you really want to lead.

**Generally speaking, prefer multiprocessing.**  Multithreading is rife with trouble, and while it *can* be faster to execute, you almost never need that speed.  That speed comes with danger, and hassle, lots of debugging time (now and later), and being very, very, careful.  Better to do what the old-timers (like me) do:  make multiprocessing your friend and dump threading in the [primarily Microsoft-centric] trash-heap of don't-go-there.